# Cannot initialize a lambda member variable with a default argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, default-arguments

I would like to compile the code below with c++17, so that I can pass any function (lambda) that has a specific signature, `int(int)`, while also allowing the default argument:

```cpp
template <class F = int(int)> // for deduction
struct A{
        A(F f = [] (int x){return x;}) : f_{f} {}

        F f_;
};

int main() {
        A work([](int x){return x + 1;});
        A not_work; // compile error.
}
```

However, clang emits an error:

```
a.cpp:6:4: error: data member instantiated with function type 'int (int)'
        F f_;
          ^
a.cpp:11:4: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<int (int)>' requested here
        A not_work;
          ^
```

I don't understand why the member `f_` can be initialized when I pass the lambda and the default lambda argument cannot be?

Meanwhile, is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message said, you can't declare a data member with a function type like `int(int)`.

When passing a lambda to the constructor, the template parameter `F` would be deduced as the lambda closure type by [CTAD (since C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction); when passing nothing `F` will use the default argument `int(int)` and the data member `f_`'s type would be `int(int)` too, which causes the error.

You might use a function pointer type ([lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) without capture could convert to function pointer implicitly) or `std::function<int(int)>`. E.g.

```
template <class F = int(*)(int)> // for deduction
struct A{
        A(F f = [] (int x){return x;}) : f_{f} {}

        F f_;
};
```

Or

```
template <class F = std::function<int(int)>> // for deduction
struct A{
        A(F f = [] (int x){return x;}) : f_{f} {}

        F f_;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have another question. Then why the line `A work([](int x){return x + 1;});` works? It seems strange to me that `work` and `not_work` object both take lambda as an argument in their ctor, while only one of them works.

Comment: @wk_j Because when you pass a lambda to `A`'s constructor, `F` is deduced to be the anonymous lambda type rather than `int(int)`, but when you supply no parameter the default of `int(int)` is used.